# Why wasn't the China-Japan-South Korea Trilateral Meeting held since 2019?

Tags: international-relations, china, japan, south-korea

> The 6th trilateral summit was held on 1 November 2015 in Seoul,
> resuming the summit since 2012 due to a variety of disputes and issues
> ranging from World War II apologies to territorial disputes among the
> three nations. During the summit, Chinese Premier Li Keqiang, Japanese
> Prime Minister Shinzō Abe, and South Korean President Park Geun-hye
> agreed to meet annually in order to work towards deepening trade
> relations with the proposed trilateral free trade agreement.[14] They
> also agreed to pursue the six-party talks over North Korea's nuclear
> weapons program.[15]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China%E2%80%93Japan%E2%80%93South_Korea_trilateral_summit

It mentions there were tensions because of Japanese provocations against South Korea and China over various historical and territorial issues, but then a meeting was held in 2019, and ever since then there has been no meeting.

Why hasn't a trilateral summit held since 2019?

> The initiative of China-Japan-South Korea Trilateral Meeting was
> started in 2008 in Fukoka, Japan. The proposal was put forward by
> former South Korean President, Lee Myung-bak to have a platform aside
> from the framework of ASEAN Plus Three forum to initiate a better
> understanding of one another in a strategically conflict ridden and
> economically volatile region. This led to the establishment of the
> Trilateral Cooperation Secretariat in Seoul in September 2011 later.
> From the year of its establishment till 2012, five Summits have been
> held. But due to disputes ranging from the apology by Japan to China
> for atrocities committed during World War II, the comfort women issue
> between ROK and Japan, to rising tensions that led to significant
> deterioration of relations between the Northeast Asian nations, no
> Summit took place after Japanese Prime Minister Abe took office in
> late 2012.

https://www.icwa.in/show_content.php?lang=1&level=3&ls_id=649&lid=590

The same thing again, but it doesn't explain the gap between 2019 and now specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Kishida [did](https://www.eastasiaforum.org/2023/05/11/kishidas-visit-to-south-korea-and-the-triumph-of-geopolitics/) visit South Korea this year. So my guess is tensions between China and one or both of the other two. I can easily point to the China-Japan tensions of this year ([over](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-66577769) Fukushima waters and what not--also [new](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/03/17/asia/japan-new-defense-base-disputed-islands-intl-hnk/index.html) Japanese military bases, and an increase in Chinese naval patrols in contested waters), but I'm not sure I can give a full account back to 2019 of all the stuff. IIRC China's leaders also avoided much meetings during zero Covid. (Someone else might be able to provide additional details.)

Oh and ["China blasts US-Japan-South Korea summit, warns of ‘contradictions and increasing tensions’"](https://apnews.com/article/china-us-japan-south-korea-6c626a246219c6dc3915ed8a18f34c74) should be self-explanatory (even though it's a recent event of this year). The new South Korean president Yoon (elected 2022) [seems](https://www.cfr.org/in-brief/whats-causing-rise-china-south-korea-tensions) to have taken a harder line on North Korea and China. (He apparently made an issue of this on the campaign trail [too](https://www.americanprogress.org/article/rising-anti-china-sentiment-in-south-korea-offers-opportunities-to-strengthen-us-rok-relations/).)